# PHP to JSP short code conversion/translation

Tags: php, json, jsp

I have a small problem, I know how to do what I do in PHP but not sure how to achive that in JSP, can anyone help?,

basically here is my code in php:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
....
....

<?php

$order_items = getCurrentAttribute('confirmation','orderitems');
$order_items = explode('||',$order_items);
$fo_order_items = array();
foreach($order_items as $item)
{
    $item = explode('|',$item);
    if(!$item[0]) continue;

    $fo_order_items[$item[0]] = array(
        $item[3],(int) $item[4],$item[1]
    );
}

?>

var fo_order_items = <?php echo json_encode($fo_order_items); ?>
....
....
....
</script>
```

and here you can find an example of how order_items variable looks at the beginning:

```
sku1|title1|size1|price1|quantity1||sku2|title2|size2|price2|quantity1
```

Thanks in advance.

P.S.
don't worry about getCurrentAttribute() function, its already done in JSP

cheers,
/Marcin

Comment: It's always easier to get help from the SO community if you show us what you have tried yourself. I'm all about helping people, not doing their jobs. If you're building a JSP application you'll need at least some experience with Java. Give it a try, and I'm sure someone will help you finish it :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
String items[] = order_items.split("||") ;

List<String> list = Arrays.asList(items); 
HashMap map = new HashMap();
for( String i : list )
{ 
    String it[] = i.split("|");
    if(!it[0].equals(null)) continue;
     map.put(it[0] , new Object(){ it[3] , it[4] , it[1]});


}
```

// i guess it may help
// for json encoding look at JSON - LIB or GSON lib

Comment: Thanks @Preetam but what is the final object as it looks like map is always getting overwritten?